# How to validate credentials in laravel 5 for logging in features?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I am using tutorial for web app. Tutorial uses Laravel 4 whereas I am using Laravel 5. I solved register issue but when I set down to test for login following errors shown up:

> ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 111: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\user given, called in C:\Users\Pujan\Desktop\projectlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php on line 390 and defined.

I'm not able to figure out the issue here. What actually means credentials. I know Laravel 5 has inbuilt login features but couldn't use it so I tried out different ways but this problem out of my focus.
My usercontroller is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use View;

use App\user;
use Input;
use App\Http\Requests\YourFormRequest;
use Auth;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public $restful = true;

    public function index()
    {

        return View::make('users.new')->with('title', 'Make it snappy Q&A - Register');
    }


    public function create(YourFormRequest $request)
    {
        User::create($request->all());

        return redirect('/')->with('message','Thanks for registering!');
    }

    public function getlogin()
    {
       // return \Auth::user();
        return View::make('users.login')->with('title','Make it snappy Q&A - Login ');
    }

    public function createlogin()
    {
        $user = array(
            'username'=>Input::get('username'),
            'password'=>Input::get('password')
            );
        if (Auth::attempt($user))
        {
            return redirect('/')->with('message','You are logged in:');
        }else{
            return redirect('login')
            ->with('message','Your username or password are incorrect pls chk it out')
            ->with_input();
        }
    }
```

I have my routes:

```
Route::get('/','Questions@index');
Route::get('register','UserController@index');
Route::get('login','UserController@getlogin');
Route::post('register','UserController@create');
Route::post('login','UserController@createlogin');
```

My login layout is working properly but as I try to login above errors show up. I think this error belongs to inbuilt Laravel 5 features but I am not able to match the setting inbuilt and my created login functionality.

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.0 or 5.1? In 5.0, authentication( login system ) is already setup and in 5.1 you can follow [official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) to setup the authentication sytem

Comment: 12th line of your controller should be `use App\User;`, not `use App\user;`

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing isn't related to your login code. Your `User` entity should implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface. An interface is a contract, it lists methods/functions that a class must have. The class definition should look like this:

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
```

On a quick glance of your code, there are other things you can do to clean it up:

```
public function createlogin()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(Input::only('username', 'password'))) {
        return redirect('/')->with('message','You are logged in:');
    }

    return redirect('login')
        ->with('message','Your username or password are incorrect pls chk it out')
        ->with_input();
}
```

And on a final note, I'd stop using the tutorial you're following. Laravel's latest documentation has a quick start guide that covers authentication, there are two versions, [beginnner](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart) and [intermediate](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart-intermediate).

Comment: Thank you @Logan Bailey for information. I am using inbuilt auth but still it didnot redirected to home page with logged in message instead shows login page with old input.How can i figure out this problem

Comment: @anandshrestha57 That most likely indicates a validation error.

Answer (score 0):

What @Logan has suggested is true, and you should follow that.

I'll just go with cleaning of your code a bit.

Whenever you are dealing with validations, you should treat it as a separate stuff and for that you need to create the `FormRequest` object.

Refer [this document](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation) on how to create the form request.

Then update the `authorize` and `rules` method with the following:

```
/**
 * Authorize the request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'required|exists:users|alpha_dash|min:4',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Now in your `createLogin` method

```
/**
 * Log in the user.
 *
 * @param \App\Http\Requests\YourFileRequest $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function createlogin(YourFileRequest $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect('/')->with('message','You are logged in:');
    }

    return redirect('login')
        ->with('message', 'Invalid credentials')
        ->with_input();
}
```

Now you see how your code is simple and readable when you visit after 6 months from now ? It has to be like that. `Validation` logic in separate file and your `Login` logic in the controller. According to me, this helps a lot when you are testing via phpUnit, phpSpec or any other testing tool you are using.

Me and Logan have also replaced your `if` statement block. That is because, you should avoid the `else` block as far as possible when you are returning something from both `if` and `else` block.

**Just a side note:**

1. You should always try to follow 3 principles while programming / coding: [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
2. Kindly document your code whenever you are done with that part of the code. This is will again help future programmers and also for future reference to know what that piece of code is doing.

Hope this helps you out. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you @user3514160 for valuable suggestion. When i sat down to test again it is not redirected to home page with message you are logged in:

Comment: instead it stays in same page with no error with old input. Where i am mistaken again @user3514160

Comment: Kindly update the question with what you are trying.. And what is the error that you are getting... Also post the code of the test that you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you have solved this issue or not but I'm putting my experience here, maybe it could help someone else looking for a solution to this problem which happened exactly with me.

Your App/User model class should extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` and not the Eloquent Model.

So change your User model to this:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
```

Instead of

```
class User extends Model
```

It did resolve this same error for me. Hope this helps.